# Scaled pricing and inventory management

Tags: configuration, tierprice

I have a limited edition product the price of each edition has to go up, as the previous edition is sold. I.e.  1st edition is 1000, 2nd edition is 1100, 3rd edition is 1200. Each edition can only be released when the previous edition is sold. How can this be managed?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default Magento functionality to do this. So you will either have to do this yourself or build an extension that, via a cronjob or observer checks the stock of the last product and enables the next product.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a cron as previously mentioned, however with books you normally have thousands so often is not realistic therefore you need dynamic pricing which Magento does not support. We licensed it instead, complex area dynamic pricing.

Comment: Stop trying to pitch your own services. Not to mention that a cron would be entirely unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

A cron wouldn't work for this as you'll need the price change to come into effect immediately following a sale, so the simplest way would just be to attach an event on the successful order observer that increments the pricing of the given products.

Depending on your sales volume, this could work without fault, or could cause catastrophic locking issues during  repeated product save.

What would also work is adding logic to the price method itself to calculate based on data in the sales flat order table.